# Can you retrieve multiple information from one Scanner instance in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, io, java.util.scanner

For my assignment we were asked to do a load/save button through a GUI. To my understanding we are not using `java.io.File`, but instead saving the information needed as text, then loading the text through a `Scanner` instance.

My question is: 
if I give the scanner a block of text, should the text to assign to member variables be separated by commas? or should each separate set of info be on a different line?

I understand there will be a bunch of getters and maybe one setter but I am very unfamiliar with I/O in this regard and am not sure how to retrieve the information correctly.

Comment: Are you asking about the recommended file content format or how to implement file I/O in Java?

Comment: How to implement file I/O in Java

Comment: Scanner can read your text regardless of how it is separated by lines. You might want to rephrase your question to make clear what you want exactly.

Comment: edit: When the Save button is pressed, display all the data using System.out.print and System.out.println statements. Do this so you can read back all the data when the Load button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

From how you worded your question, it appears that the specific format in which info is saved is left up to you. So pick something that makes sense to you. Once you have the format nailed down, then you can start thinking about how to read/write info.

For file reading/writing, the Java API is a good place to start: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

I'd recommend looking at the `File`, `Scanner`, and `FileWriter` classes in there. Those should give you the basic tools needed to perform file I/O.

Comment: Don't forget the `Files` class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you have a block text that you want to handover to a Scanner and read it you can do it either way as comma separated, Any other delimiter or line separated. I have the couple of samples with outputs hope it helps.

New Line separated block of text:

```
String blockOfText = "age=10\nshape=rectangle\nabc\n123\ndd\n20\nxyz";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(blockOfText);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\n");

        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

Comma separated block of text:

```
String blockOfText = "age=10,shape=rectangle,abc,123,dd,20,xyz";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(blockOfText);
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");

        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

**Same Output from both:**
age=10
shape=rectangle
abc
123
dd
20
xyz